# Magento 2.2 : _theme.less file override not working

Tags: magento2.2.2

I am new to magento2 development and  have tried every possible senario's but still unable to reproduce the issue why my _theme.less file is not overriding existing styles.I have put my less file inside source folder.

Please find below senario's.

In my parent theme

```
.header . content have max-width:1280px
```

In my theme.less file

```
.header .content have max-width:1100px
```

Comment: waiting for suggestions from all of you

Comment: I am a new Magento 2 developer as well. and I find it the steepest learning curve of any CMS. Why do they have to have such a horrible DX. Just make it like wordpress already. And yes I am still stuck on this exact same thing.

Comment: Can anyone have video tutorial uploaded for same css overriding?.it will be a great help for developers like us who are stuck with this thing to overcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can override below file :

> /lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout.less

In your theme :

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout.less

Changed in line No. 12

```
@layout__max-width: 1280px;
```

**TO**

```
@layout__max-width: 1100px;
```

Comment: working perfect..! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put an empty file in theme_dir/web/css/source/_theme.less. The blank file will override the _theme.less file.
After that run :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```